# curl in Docker container fails b/c of ssl

Tags: ssl, curl, docker, certificate, self-signed

When I do a curl to my site from my host like :
`curl -v https://my.host.name:443/some/text?WSDL` I get the desired output.
But when I change into my docker container `docker exec -it /bin/bash` and execute the exact same command, it fails with `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`. With `-k` it works, but I don't think this should be the solution. There is no proxy. I have **cntlm** installed, but set this IP and hostname to the **no-proxy section**. A **traceroute** also looks the same.
The container is from ruby 2.3.1, but nothing changed (except the code I copied there)

Why is it not working from inside the container?

Comment: I think you have to add your public certficate inside your container

Comment: Are you able to post the chain of the SSL? Where was the certificate purchased? This sounds like the CA is a custom one and isn't added in the container image.

Comment: I created a volume in my docker-compose.yml so that my container will have the same certificates as my host (`- /var/lib/ca-certificates/pem/:/etc/ssl/certs/  -/etc/ssl/private/:/etc/ssl/private/`). I can not post the chain though. The certificate is purchased through our internal company support for certificates. I can not say were exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments said, I have to have the certificates in my container. The volume I set up somehow wasn't build at first to the container, but with the second try/build it worked like it does on the host.